# How to Automate the chrome Extension without manual click on extension button to run at the launch of website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any possibility of running the chrome extension automatically without manual intervention at the launch of specific URL.

If possible, please provide the example how it can be achieved.

Comment: You can run content scripts automatically with the `content_scripts` entry of the manifest file. You can also use some chrome APIs in the background page to detect when a URL is being opened in a tab (for example, `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`) and run code accordingly

Comment: Hi @IvánNokonoko. I tried both the options but nothing is happening. When I opening the url in chrome nothing is happening until I press the browser_Action button. Any In-site on the same will be very helpful.